# How to download Google 360 Photo Sphere as 1 image?

Tags: images, download, photos, google-maps

How can I download Google 360 Photo Sphere ?
I checked out Google Chrome Developer Tools Resources tab, and every photo sphere it seems is stitched together with tens or hundreds of images, and it would take a long time to put them all together on a photo editor such as Photoshop. Is there any way I can download a photo sphere as one image ?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the website mentioned below and follow the instructions. They use an application to download the 360° photos.
https://svd360.istreetview.com

Answer (score 1):

Also possible via [google takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout?pli=1). You get all your Google Sphere images though.
[screenprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXIc0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can add post on your Google Plus, add your photo to post(from google album) and open it. You will be able to download Hi-Res image.

[image]